# Unity - Proper rotation of object from 3 points in space

Tags: unity

I have a rectangular object (for now), with children placed partially in it in its forward, up, and right sides (to make rotations easier to track).

I am trying to get the object to rotate according to 3 points in space. One is the origin (0,0,0), one is in the forward direction (0,0,1), and one is in the right direction (1,0,0).

The origin and forward direction are how I define the origin and direction, so these coordinates are local. I assume for now that the right direction is correct for now.

My simple solution was to set `transform.forward = (forward-origin);` and `transform.right = (right-origin);` (where the points are given in global coordinates).

My problem with this is that the rectangular object won't roll around its forward direction. I'm not great with geometry, but I can't get past the thought that setting `right` ought to solve that problem.

I was, however, not surprised to see that trying to set `transform.up` as the cross-product of those two made things worse and the object was no longer facing in the forward direction.

So,

1. Why doesn't the combination of `forward` and `right` account for this rolling?
2. What if `right` weren't *exactly* right? I'm assuming simply normalizing it against `forward` would do it (and with unity, I could also get `up` out of it with one function call), but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set one direction vector at a time, Unity doesn't know you're about to set another one. The semantics of the language make each assignment a separate operation, and it needs to give you a complete new orientation after each one, not a partial transformation-in-progress.

So if you set `transform.forward = foo`, Unity has 2 of 3 degrees of freedom specified, and it has to *guess* what you wanted for the third. Sometimes it will guess wrong.

Then if you set `transform.right = bar`, Unity again has 2 of 3 degrees of freedom specified, and it has to *guess again*. Sometimes it will guess wrong.

It doesn't know the two operations are connected - for all it can tell, you changed your mind after the first assignment, and now want a completely different, unrelated orientation from the second assignment. (If it didn't make this assumption, transform operations would have a "memory" you'd have to manually clear between uses, which would be clunky)

If you want *both* forward *and* right to point in particular directions, you need to express that as a single transformation, not as two separate steps. Here's one way to do it:

```
Vector3 forwardDirection = forwardPosition - origin;
Vector3 rightDirection = rightPosition - origin;
Vector3 upDirection = Vector3.Cross(forwardDirection, rightDirection);

Quaternion orientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardDirection, upDirection);

transform.rotation = orientation;
```

This will give you an orientation whose forward vector points exactly along your chosen forward direction, and whose right vector points as close as it can along your chosen right direction while still obeying the first constraint (since we have only 1 degree of freedom left).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. But I've tried it your way, and I get a gimbal lock. I could be wrong, but aren't 3 non-colinear points enough to get the transformation with no degrees of freedom left? (Now that I'm thinking about it, suddenly it does sound like I'm wrong, but I can't think straight anymore...)

Comment: 3 non-collinear points are indeed enough to get a transformation with no degrees of freedom left. The origin gives you the position, the forward vector uses up 2 of the 3 degrees of freedom in orientation, and the third point uses up the last degree of freedom. Can you explain the specific symptoms that you're describing as "gimbal lock"? Since there are no gimbals in the code above, it's possible these symptoms are due to something else.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't do the exact same thing then, I recall using one of the functions of the sort, with the second parameter being `up`, and using the cross product there. I got the object to always look in the right direction, but when rotating it around, it would sometimes suddenly rotate around its `forward` direction, which it definitely shouldn't have. I'll copy-paste your code tomorrow when I'm back at the lab and try it.

Comment: I couldn't make it to the lab yesterday, but I managed to get there today, and it works perfectly. Guess I what I did was similar but wrong. Answer accepted, and thank you!