# How to set transform.up without locking the y-axis?

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion

I'm trying to make an object's transform.up to a normal of the raycastHit point. I tried using this line of code:

```
transform.up = Vector3.Lerp(transform.up, normal, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
```

This works well but locks the y-axis rotation as a result the object can't rotate and just keeps going forward. I tried using Quaternion.LookRotation. But I couldn't make it affect the object's rotation. Here is what I tried:

```
bodyRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, normal);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, bodyRotation, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
```

How can I set the transform.up without locking the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a value to `transform.right`/`up`/`forward`, you're implicitly telling Unity "I care *only* about the direction of this one axis - do whatever is cheap and easy with the other two". [If you care about both the up and forward direction, then you need to take responsibility for constructing a quaternion with your desired orientation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/183801/39518).

Fortunately, this is easy, as I've covered in [several](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/167395/39518) [past](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100887/39518) [answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/133357/39518):

```
Quaternion TurretLookRotation(Vector3 approximateForward, Vector3 exactUp) {
    Quaternion zToUp = Quaternion.LookRotation(exactUp, -approximateForward);
    Quaternion yToz = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
    return zToUp * yToz;
}
```

You can incorporate this like so:

```
var targetRotation = TurretLookRotation(transform.forward, normal);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I've used `RotateTowards` in place of `Lerp`/`Slerp` here, because [your lerping expressions were not not correctly adjusting for `deltaTime`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518).

Comment: It does unlock the y-axis. But the rotation is a bit jittery on terrain: https://youtu.be/XHmikK0MXiA

Comment: Then you can reduce the `speed` variable. If that doesn't solve it, then you may have another script fighting with this one for control of the rotation.